# Simple Question: division of sums

Tags: asymptotics, ratio

I am a little bit confused about the following simple task. 
Given some functions $f(x), g(x), h(x), l(x), m(x)$.

We know that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= m(x)$.

We further know that $h(x), l(x)$ are asymptotically smaller than $f(x), g(x)$ and $g(x)$ is asymptotically smaller than $f(x)$.

Now I would like to show that

$$\frac{f(x)+h(x)}{g(x)+l(x)}= m(x) + o(f(x)).$$

How does one show this? It should be true, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac{f+h}{g+l} - \frac{f}{g} = \frac{h}{g+l} - \frac{fl}{g(g+l)} \in o(1) + o(f) = o(f)$. Thus $\frac{f+h}{g+l} = \frac{f}{g}+o(f) = m + o(f)$.

Comment: I do not really get, why you need this step $m + \frac{h}{g} + o(f)$. Isn't it just $\frac{f+h}{g+l}=\frac{f}{g}+o(f)=m+o(f)$, where the first equation follows from your first calculation?

Comment: I tried to solve your problem from basic principles. It is true that if $l \in o(g)$ then $\frac{f+h}{g+l}$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{f+h}{g}$ but I didn't know whether you were allowed to use that fact.

Comment: I accepted your answer and gave you an upvote. Thanks for your help. But anyway, I still do not get the middle one, since $\frac{f}{g}=m$, and this is all you need to get from the third last to the last term in the second equation, isn't it? (Sorry if I don't get obvious things. I am a bit slow sometimes)

Comment: You're right, the $\frac{h}{g}$ is a mistake from me incorrectly editing my answer. I'll remove it.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at it again. It makes perfectly sense now! Great!!